# Eraser in Android View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I'm creating an application to draw on canvas.  To draw I set the pen color to black.

for pen button

```
 int black = Color.BLACK;
 mDrawPaint = new DrawPaint(Capture.this, null,black);
```

where DrawPaint extends View

Now to create eraser I just changed the pen color to white that is the background color of the canvas. Like this

for eraser button

```
 int white = Color.WHITE;
 mDrawPaint = new DrawPaint(Capture.this, null,white);
```

But again if I select the pen button which has pen color black and draw something on canvas, it again automatically redraws the previous paint what I drew before erasing it. Also the eraser erases a big rectangular area. Please explain me what is going wrong. Thank you.

Here is the DrawPaint Constructor

```
 public DrawPaint(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int color) {

    super(context, attrs);
    this.destroyDrawingCache();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);

}




    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        eventX = event.getX();
        eventY = event.getY();
        button1.setEnabled(true);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            lastTouchX = eventX;
            lastTouchY = eventY;
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
            int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
            for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
            }
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;

        default:
            debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }

        invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: can you show the onTouchEvent() method...

Comment: ya.. Now I inserted in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Eraser you can use this code...

```
mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

and about that square color prob...

Check this out..
this is the best example for canvas drawing with erase, blur and Emboss effect...

```
public class FingerText extends Activity
    implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MyView(this));

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    //this is the line that sets the initial pen color
    mPaint.setColor(inkColor);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
}



private Paint       mPaint;
private Bitmap      mBitmap;
private boolean             inkChosen;
private int bgColor = 0xFFFFFFFF;  //set initial bg color var to white
private int inkColor =  0xFF000000; //set initial ink color var to black

public void colorChanged(int color) {
    //This is the implementation of the interface from colorpickerdialog.java

    if (inkChosen){
            mPaint.setColor(color);
            inkColor = color;
    }
    else {
            mBitmap.eraseColor  (color);
            bgColor = color;
            //set the color to the user's last ink color choice
            mPaint.setColor(inkColor); 
    }



}

public class MyView extends View {



    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

    public MyView(Context c) {
        super(c);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        //this sets the bg color for the bitmap
        mBitmap.eraseColor  (bgColor);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //this is the line that changes the bg color in the initial canvas
            canvas.drawColor(bgColor);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

private static final int BG_COLOR_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int INK_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
private static final int CLEAR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
private static final int ERASER_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
private static final int SEND_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(0, BG_COLOR_ID, 0, "Background Color").setShortcut('3', 'b');
    menu.add(0, INK_MENU_ID, 0, "Ink Color").setShortcut('4', 'c');
    menu.add(0, CLEAR_MENU_ID, 0, "Clear All").setShortcut('5', 'e');
    menu.add(0, ERASER_MENU_ID, 0, "Eraser").setShortcut('6', 'x');
    menu.add(0, SEND_MENU_ID, 0, "Send").setShortcut('7', 's');

    /****   Is this the mechanism to extend with filter effects?
    Intent intent = new Intent(null, getIntent().getData());
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    menu.addIntentOptions(
                          Menu.ALTERNATIVE, 0,
                          new ComponentName(this, NotesList.class),
                          null, intent, 0, null);
    *****/
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    mPaint.setXfermode(null);
    mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case BG_COLOR_ID:
                    new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
                    inkChosen = false;
                    return true;
        case INK_MENU_ID:
            new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
            //remember the user's last ink choice color so we can revert after eraser
            //to background color change -- otherwise ink is last bg color
            inkColor = mPaint.getColor();
            inkChosen = true;
            return true;
        case CLEAR_MENU_ID:
            mBitmap.eraseColor  (bgColor);
            return true;
        case ERASER_MENU_ID:
            //set pen color to bg color for 'erasing'
            mPaint.setColor(bgColor);
            return true;
        case SEND_MENU_ID:
                    /* TODO need to decide whether to save image locally
                     * and how to make it available if so. really only need to
                     * save if we want to let users view later, or pick a
                     * previous message to send again 
                     */

                    // this try-catch block creates a private file and an
                    // inputstream pointing to it for reading
            FileInputStream ifs;
                            try {
                                    FileOutputStream fs = openFileOutput("message_image", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    mBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fs);
                                    ifs = openFileInput("message_image");
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    return true;
                            }
                                    // inserts file pointed to by ifs into image gallery
                            String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ifs),
                                    "Message image1", "Message image");

                                    // alternative: inserts mBitmap into image gallery
/*              String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                                mBitmap, "Message image1", "Message image");
*/
                                    // creates the Intent to open the messaging app
                                    // with the image at url attached
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Message created using FingerText"); 
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
            sendIntent.setType("image/png");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
                    /* TODO delete the image from the content provider
                     * following line deletes the image, but too soon!
                     */
//              getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(url), null, null);


            //this resets canvas after send   
            //could also reset to last user settings w/o var resets
            bgColor = 0xFFFFFFFF;  //set bg color var back to white
            inkColor =  0xFF000000; //set ink color var back to black
            mBitmap.eraseColor  (bgColor);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you need mCanvas? Isn't enough to work with canvas from onDraw()? It seems to me that you are drawing twice the same thing.

Comment: just a temporary canvas which shows drawing when i draw and path will inflate on the view's canvas when Action_UP call...

Comment: @Laviniux if i call canvas of onDraw() it takes bit high for processing so i just take another canvas which draw the path for me when i action_down and action_move which light for processing and when Action_Up called Canvas of onDraw() call...

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Actually, invalidate() method from onTouchEvent will call onDraw() (please see the documentation), for each operation (ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP), so I think this implementation will require more resources than removing mCanvans. I asked because I am drawing some lines on my canvas without a temporary canvas and it works.The difference is that I need instant update, I need to see the changes from ACTION_MOVE, so it is not enough to call onDraw only in ACTION_UP

Comment: @SilentKiller Actually i have also used m_Paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)); for erasing, but there is a problem using this can u look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229496/eraser-with-porterduff-mode-clear-always-draws-a-transparent-line